# How to structure a cart with cart products object

Tags: object, oop, domain-driven-design

I am new to DDD and I am having trouble structuring an object. I have a `cart`, where I can  add `products` to it. Each `product` has some properties like image, title, price, etc. Whenever a `product` is added to the `cart`, the database stores this relation in a separate table, called `cart_products`. This new table allows me to add some new properties to the `cart product`, like an observation, it has an id different from that of the `product` in the `products` table, it can have additionals like "fries for a cheeseburguer", so on. So, if I am working on a `cart` object, which has `products` (which come from the `cart_products` table), should I have a `cart.products`, which would be an array of `products`, where each `product` will be a `cart_product`, with an id, observation and then a property `product` which has all the properties of product, like image, title, price, or I can have all these properties directly inside my product? Basically.

```
cart = {
  products = [                        // this product comes from `cart_products` table
   id = 1
   observation = 'text text text'
   product = {                        // this product comes from `products` table
    image: 'url'
    name: 'Cheese'
    price: 2.0
   }
  ]
}
```

or

```
cart = {
  products = [                        // this product comes from `cart_products` table
   id = 1
   observation = 'text text text'
   image: 'url'                       // this property comes from `products` table
   name: 'Cheese'                     // this property comes from `products` table
   price: 2.0                         // this property comes from `products` table
  ]
}
```

Using the idea of Ubiquitous Language, it seems like the second fits better, but I don't know it that's correct (or, at least, makes more sense)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to redefine your `cart_products`. This isn't just a table to join two other tables, but has real value. Doing so will help you to think about your data structures more easily.

Your objects could have the following definitions and responsibilities:

- Cart - Contains all the products that a user has selected, will also need fields to identify what user it's associated to, etc. This is an aggregate root in your DDD approach.
- CartLineItem - Refers to a snapshot of product that a user wants to purchase along with some supplementary information. Can only exist when associated to a Cart.
- Product - From the perspective of the cart, this is essentially reference data. Managing a product is a back-office task, whereas managing a cart is driven by the user. This is a hint that it should be a separate domain altogether, and be it's own aggregate root.

Taking this in to account, you'd end up with two separate completely separate object hierarchies:

```
cart = {
    userId = 4,
    // more properties
    lines = [
        productId = 1,
        name = "Cheese",
        unitPrice = 2.0,
        quantity = 5,
        discountPercent = 20
        total price = 8.0,
        observation = "bla bla bla"
    ]
}

product = {
    id = 1,
    image = "URL",
    name = "Cheese"
    price = 2.0,
    description = "Tasty cheese"
}
```

I've added in a few extra properties to hopefully show why although a cart line item represents a product, it is worth being a first-class object in its own right.

You could copy some relevant fields across to the line item for ease of access, as I have done with name and price, as you'll then get a snapshot of the product when it was added to the cart. These fields are likely to be the ones shown on a cart summary page, etc. You definitely don't need to be copying around fields like product description to your cart, and having a completely separate product domain allows for you to keep this isolated.